# XPath within R using XML package

Tags: r, xpath

I am new to XPath, but I can see how powerful it is.  I am looking at the source code of this [link](http://forums.epicgames.com/archive/index.php/t-672775.html) and simply want to extract the contents and username from the following two pieces of the page, which for simplicity sake are located near the top of the source code.

> content="[Archive]  Simburgur's Live
>   Stream [Offline] Gears of War 3"

```
<div class="username">Simburgur</div>
```

Here is my code within R:

```
doc <- htmlParse("http://forums.epicgames.com/archive/index.php/t-672775.html")
xpathSApply(doc, "//head/meta[@name=\"description\"]")
```

which returns

```
[[1]]
<meta name="description" content="[Archive]  Simburgur's Live Stream [Offline] Gears of War 3" />
```

Obviously, in this example, all I want is what is inside the quotes of content= but am stuck and can not seem to get my expression to return the string I want.

I repeat.  I am new to XPath.  :)

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for two short and efficient solutions. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/head/meta[@name='description']/@content
```

**This still selects an attribute node**, but probably there is an easy way in your PL to get the string value of the attribute.

**To get just the string value, use**:

```
string(/*/head/meta[@name='description']/@content)
```

**Do note**: Using the `//` abbreviation may result in very slow evaluation of the XPath expression, because it may cause a linear traversal of a whole (sub)tree.

**Always avoid using `//`** if the structure of the XML document is statically known .

Answer (score 3):

You're close. This should do it.

```
//head/meta[@name=\"description\"]/@content
```

The brackets are constraining the choice of meta tags, but you still have to specify the attribute you want.