# How to get table data from html table in xml?

Tags: html, r, xml-parsing, html-table

I have one xml file which has some html content like bold, paragraph and tables. I have written shell script to parse all html tags except tables. I'm using XML (R package) to parse the data.

```
<Root>
    <Title> This is dummy xml file </Title>
    <Content> This table summarises data in BMC format.
        <div class="abctable">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"   class="coder">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="50%">ABC</th>
                        <th width="50%">Weight status</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>are 18.5</td>
                        <td>arew</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>18.5 &amp;mdash; 24.9</td>
                        <td>rweq</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>25.0 &amp;mdash; 29.9</td>
                        <td>qewrte</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>30.0 and hwerqer</td>
                        <td>rwqe</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>40.0 rweq rweq</td>
                        <td>rqwe reqw</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </Content>
    <Section>blah blah blah</Section>
</Root>
```

How to parse the content of this table which in present in xml?

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a function called `readHTMLTable` in the `XML` package, that seems to do just what you need ?

Here is a way to do it with the following xml file :

```
<Root>
    <Title> This is dummy xml file </Title>
    <Content>
      This table summarises data in BMC format.

     <div class="abctable">
     <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"   class="coder">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
       <th width="50%">ABC</th><th width="50%">Weight status</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>are 18.5</td>
       <td>arew</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>18.5 &amp;mdash; 24.9</td>
       <td>rweq</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>25.0 &amp;mdash; 29.9</td>
       <td>qewrte</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>30.0 and hwerqer</td>
       <td>rwqe</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>40.0 rweq rweq</td>
       <td>rqwe reqw</td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
   </Content>
 </div>
 <Section>blah blah blah</Section>
 </Root>
```

If this is saved in a file called `/tmp/data.xml` then you can use the following code :

```
doc <- htmlParse("/tmp/data.xml")
tableNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//table")
tb <- readHTMLTable(tableNodes[[1]])
```

Which fives :

```
R> tb
                 V1            V2
1               ABC Weight status
2          are 18.5          arew
3 18.5 &mdash; 24.9          rweq
4 25.0 &mdash; 29.9        qewrte
5  30.0 and hwerqer          rwqe
6    40.0 rweq rweq     rqwe reqw
```

Comment: If look at the command help page and its examples (`?readHTMLTable`), it seems that you just have to parse your XML, then select one `<table>` element and use `readHTMLTable` on it to get the values. All of this is done with functions of the XML package.

Comment: I made an attmpt to parse the above xml file (data.xml)  : doc = xmlTreeParse("data.xml", useInternal = TRUE, encoding="UTF-8")    top = xmlRoot(doc)    table<-top[[2]]    readHTMLTable[table]  but i get error message: Error in readHTMLTable[table] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Updated my answer with a working example (almost copy/pasted from the help page, by the way).

Comment: i have uploaded one xml file at http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=ZBwog. With this i cannot parse two tables using your code. Can u pls help me where i m wrong.

Comment: First, your xml file is not well-formed, most of your tags are converted to entities. Second, please read the help page of `readHTMLTable` to understand how to parse several tables in a file.

Answer (score 1):

The best method for xml parsing would be to use xpath expressions

[Xpath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)

[Xpath and R](http://www.omegahat.org/RSXML/shortIntro.html)

[How to use XPath and R stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870207/xpath-within-r-using-xml-package)