# how to parse a huge file with certain text

Tags: regex, r

I have this huge file and it has bunch of entries in it. I would like to only read entries that contain certain values like "db_call".

I have tried this:

```
df<-read.table(text=readLines("H:/ap.log")[grepl("db_call")])
```

I get this error:

argument "x" is missing, with no default

any ideas?

Comment: Can't you use xpath or xquery?

Comment: @Fede, I am not familiar with those, are the r package?

Comment: You can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870207/xpath-within-r-using-xml-package

Comment: I would definitely separate all those function calls first, especially if the file is "huge".  You need an `x` value in the `grepl` call.

Comment: The `x` argument of `grepl` is missing - `grepl` takes at least two arguments, `pattern` and `x`, but only `pattern` was specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a test file:

```
writeLines(c("aaa 11","aaa 22","bbb 33"),con="test.txt")
```

The brute-force method (essentially the approach you tried above) is to read in the entire thing and then take only the pieces you want:

```
xx <- readLines("test.txt")
xx <- xx[grepl("aaa",xx,fixed=TRUE)]
##  (fixed=TRUE is slightly faster if you don't need regular expressions)
read.table(text=xx)
```

If you have a big file, I would recommend using `grep` at the system level (install Cygwin if necessary as you seem to be using Windows) and using `pipe`, e.g.

Test -- see how many lines contain the target string:

```
system('grep "aaa" <text.txt | wc')
```

Read only lines containg `aaa`:

```
read.table(pipe('grep "aaa" <test.txt'))
```

This will be much more efficient than reading the whole thing into R and then selecting the parts you want.

Comment: Just curious...how can you tell from the question that the OP is using Windows?

Comment: their file path is `H:/ap.log`, which looks pretty windows-y to me.

Comment: Gotcha.  Yeah, I just switched to a linux-based so I'm still learning the differences.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I get this error: no lines available in input

Comment: @user1471980 do you get any other errors? Like not finding "grep"? Did you install cygwin and configure it properly?

Comment: does the brute-force method work? can you use `grep "pattern" <inputfile.txt | wc` successfully in a command window?

Comment: @Ben Bolker, is there any other way to do this? I cannot install cygwin due to security issues?

Comment: if you can't install cygwin, or any other `grep` program for Windows (e.g. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm), and you want to do this *fast*, you will probably have to write your own C++ code (e.g. via Rcpp) to re-implement `grep` for yourself. I don't know of any built-in or packaged functions for R that implement row filtering, in part because `grep` exists already.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I used another system which had cygwin and it worked and it was really fast. I have another quick question about tailing a file but will post it as another questions.

Comment: @Ben Bolker, I got the grep working but for some files, I get this error: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 43 did not have 16 elements, how do you get around this error?

Comment: Can't possibly say without a reproducible example -- sorry.